# Evaluate expression with in-function variable calculation

Tags: r, eval, environment, rlang

Basically, I want to create an `add_trend` function that will bind to the original dataset. However, I want to do it using an expression. For example `.t` = linear trend, `.t + .t^2` = quadratic trend.

```r
.data <- tibble::tibble(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100))


add_trend <- function(.data, .f = NULL) {

  .t <- 1:NROW(.data)

  .expr <- quote(.f)
  eval(.expr)
}

add_trend(.data, .t^2)
#> Error in eval(.expr): object '.t' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

It has to do something with the environment that it is evaluated. If I store `.t` in the `Global_Env` then the function works, but when it's done inside the function then the above error shows up. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The error its telling you that it can not find the foward pipe operator (%>%). You must load dplyr / tidyverse packages first.

Comment: It's also very odd to prefix all your functions with periods. That usually means they are "hidden" variables. Is that really what you want? Are you trying to use the `rlang` evaluation? Because `quote()` and `eval()` are base R functions, not `rlang` versions.

Comment: @SantiagoCapobianco it was a bad reprex, the problem is not in the pipe.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't know If I know the theory about the dot-suffix I just do it to get around conflicts. What do you suggest? `enexpr` - `eval_bare` or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `substitute` rather than `quote`:

```
add_trend <- function(.data, .f = NULL) {
  .t <- 1:NROW(.data)
  .expr <- substitute(.f)
  eval(.expr)
}
```

---

From `help("quote")`

> `substitute` returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression
>   `expr`, substituting any variables bound in env.
>
> `quote` simply returns its argument. The argument is not evaluated and
>   can be any R expression.